# Muon Discover toolbar has disappeared

Tags: kubuntu

I am running Kubuntu 14.04.2, and have Muon Discover as my package manager.  I accidentally right clicked the tool bar and toggled "Show toolbar" off, so now my toolbar is disappear.  I want to get it back, but I can't seem to figure out a way to restore it.  Anybody have any advice?  Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Right click in the area above the search bar at the top of Muon Package Manager. A "Main Toolbar" pop up window will appear, place a check mark in the box. I turned it off, then did the above action and it came back on. Chapter 4.2 Muon Package Manager clued me in.